# Can I move both conditions into 1 condition

Tags: bash

I've only been doing scripting a few weeks, and I've managed to write the script at the bottom of this post and get it to work.  However, I know that what I need to do *really* is move the bottom if statement condition into the if statement above.  So I need to do a condition like this:

If file exists (and isn't a empty string) AND is either one of these 2: ("switchport mode access" OR "switchport trunk allowed vlan").

I feel that if I did something like the below (not sure the syntax is correct, but doesn't matter because I'm just explaining):

```
     ###### 1 #####        ################ 2 ####################     ######## 3 ########
if ([ ! -z "${prev}" ] && [ "$line" = "switchport access vlan $i" ] || [[ $line =~ $regex ]]);then
```

Then I'm worried I don't understand how it groups it.  So if we call each condition 1,2,3.  So does it mean condition 1&2 OR 3.  Or does this man condition 1 & (2-OR-3)?  Like, is there a way I could even clear up any ambiguity like you would in maths by putting brackets around the bits you want to group.  What's the right way to do it?

```
tmpfiles="$PWD/configs/*.tmp"
prev=
for basefile in $tmpfiles
do
while read line
do
    ## get old vlans and interfaces
    for i in "${oldvlans[@]}"
    do
        if ([ ! -z "${prev}" ] && [ "$line" = "switchport access vlan $i" ]);then
            line1="${prev}"
            line2="${line}"
            echo "${line1}"
            echo "${line2}"
        fi
    done
    ### check for lines with "trunk allowed vlans" on and do a no trunk allowed vlan on them
    regex="switchport trunk allowed vlan*"
    if [ ! -z "${prev}" ] && [[ $line =~ $regex ]];then
        line1="${prev}"
        line2="${line}"
        echo "${line1}"
        echo "no ${line2}"
    fi

    prev="${line}"
done < "$basefile" > "$basefile.done"
```

EDIT: I did some testing below to try and work out the logic since stephane said () is not for grouping test conditions, and I'm confident I proved him/her wrong):

```
$ var1=sumit ; [ -z "var1" ] && ([ "$var1" = "sxxt" ] || [ "$var1" = "sumit" ]);  echo $?
1
$ var1=sumit ; [ -n "var1" ] && ([ "$var1" = "sxxt" ] || [ "$var1" = "sumit" ]);  echo $?
0
```

So I think this is the correct way to do a test where I want:

```
If [condition1] AND if ([condition 2] OR [condition 3] are true).
```

But I'm just hacking away at it, and need to just try and get it clarified.

Comment: `(...)` is to run subshells in `sh`, it's not for grouping nor to wrap the condition part of an if statement. For grouping commands, there's `{ ...; }`, but you don't need it there.

Comment: I mean, the bash manual tells me different: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html

Comment: Are you using bash or sh? How do you call your script? Do you have a shebang line (e.g. `#!/bin/bash`)?

Comment: yes its bash.  I chopped my code out of a bigger block to isolate my question.

Comment: Related: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Comment: @johnsmith the manual says exactly the same as Stéphane in the very section you linked to: "*Placing a list of commands between parentheses forces the shell to create a subshell*" and "*Placing a list of commands between curly braces causes the list to be executed in the current shell context. No subshell is created*".

Comment: Hi Stephane.  I've actually just proved your wrong (I don't mean to critique, but you are definitely incorrect).  I will add something to my original post to prove it.

Comment: @johnsmith Using parentheses will have the effect of grouping, but that's a side effect of forcing the contents to run in a subshell, not their primary purpose. Curly braces have grouping as their primary purpose, not just as a side effect. BTW, in bash you can use `[[ ]]` conditional expressions, which allow parentheses and `&&` and `||` inside them, making this sort of thing much easier. `[ ]` test expressions have much more limited and confusing syntax, and you shouldn't try this inside them.

Comment: @johnsmith note that Stéphane didn't say it doesn't work. He said that the `(..)` are used to run commands in subshells not for simple grouping.

Comment: Ok I guess my question still stands then.  Can either that terdon or Gordon guy write me the correct way I "should" have wrote: $ var1=sumit ; [ -z "var1" ] && ([ "$var1" = "sxxt" ] || [ "$var1" = "sumit" ]);  echo $?

Comment: as an aside, the regex `switchport trunk allowed vlan*` would match a string `switchport trunk allowed vla`, and then zero or more letters `n`. That's different from the shell pattern syntax where `*` means any number of any characters.

Comment: @johnsmith, note that the `[ -z "var1" ]` there would check to see if `var1` is an empty string. It isn't, so that test will always be falsy, which makes the whole condition meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bash, the cleanest way to do what you want is to use the `[[ ]]` construct instead of the more limited `[ ]` and combine the conditions:

```
if [ ! -z "${prev}" ] && [[ "$line" = "switchport access vlan $i" || "$line" =~ $regex ]];then
```

Which works as you expect:

```
$ var1=sumit; [ -z "var1" ] && [[ "$var1" = "sxxt" || "$var1" = "sumit" ]]; echo $?
1
$ var1=sumit; [ -n "var1" ] && [[ "$var1" = "sxxt" || "$var1" = "sumit" ]]; echo $?
0
```

Now, it is true that you can abuse the `( )` to run the tests in a subshell and check the result but it is ugly, complicated and unnecessary. If you insist on going down this route, at least avoid the subshell and use `{ }` to group the commands:

```
$ var1=sumit; [ -z "var1" ] && { [ "$var1" = "sxxt" ] || [ "$var1" = "sumit" ] ;}; echo $?
1
$ var1=sumit; [ -n "var1" ] && { [ "$var1" = "sxxt" ] || [ "$var1" = "sumit" ] ;}; echo $?
0
```

But really, if you're using bash just go for `[[ ]]`. And if using a POSIX shell, you can use `-o`:

```
$ var1=sumit; [ -z "var1" ] && [ "$var1" = "sxxt" -o  "$var1" = "sumit" ] ; echo $?
1
$ var1=sumit; [ -n "var1" ] && [ "$var1" = "sxxt" -o  "$var1" = "sumit" ] ; echo $?
0
```

Comment: Oh my god, thank you!!!  That has cleared this up beautifully.  I have only learned [] conditions and not properly learned  [[]] .  Seems like my problem is the lack of knowledge around using [[]] .  Thats great, thank you!

Comment: note that the [ -z "var1" ] there would check to see if "var1" is an empty string. It isn't, so that test will always be falsy, which makes the whole condition meaningless

Comment: @ilkkachu yes, exactly, the first part is irrelevant. I am simply reproducing the test example from the OP where they are explicitly using a string and not a variable precisely so that the first test doesn't affect the output of the second. Look at the first example for a "real" example, both here and in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this part:

> ```
>      ###### 1 #####        ################ 2 ####################     ######## 3 ########
> if ([ ! -z "${prev}" ] && [ "$line" = "switchport access vlan $i" ] || [[ $line =~ $regex ]]);then
> ```
>
> Then I'm worried I don't understand how it groups it. So if we call each condition 1,2,3. So does it mean condition 1&2 OR 3. Or does this man condition 1 & (2-OR-3)?

The shell doesn't have precedence for `&&` and `||` *in command lists* (like the above), but resolves them left to right. So if you have `A && B || C`, it gets effectively grouped as `(A && B) || C`. Similarly, `A || B && C` is `(A || B) && C`.

Which is not the same as in most other programming languages, where `&&` has precedence over `||`. And to make it worse, inside `[[ .. ]]` conditionals and  arithmetic expressions (e.g. `$(( .. ))`), that precedence is obeyed in Bash too.

So, these two are different:

```
if [[ a = a ]] || [[ a = a ]] && [[ a = b ]]; then
    echo one
fi
if [[ a = a    ||    a = a    &&    a = b ]]; then
    echo two
fi
```

(`a = a` and `a = b` are silly, of course, but will do for the example.)

It might be best to avoid using command lists for conditionals, and instead do what others have suggested and use `[[ ... ]]`.

That is, as long as you're running Bash or another shell that has it anyway, since `[[ ... ]]` isn't a standard feature. In a standard POSIX shell, you're limited to command lists.

---

As for your code, I'm not exactly sure if you'd achieve much by combining those three conditions to one conditional, even if grouped properly:

```
if [ ! -z "${prev}" ] && ( [ "$line" = "switchport access vlan $i" ] || [[ $line =~ $regex ]] ); then
```

(regardless of if you use a subshell `(foo)` or a compound group `{ foo;}` for the grouping)

Mostly because the way you have it, you'd have to do both of the two latter tests within the `${oldvlans[@]}` loop, but only one of them actually depends on the loop variable. Also the `[ ! -z "$prev" ]` condition seems like a precondition for the `while read` loop doing anything, so why not have it separately.

I'd rather split the three rather than combine them:

```
while read line
do
    if [ -z "$prev" ]; then
        continue
    fi
    ## we know "$prev" is non-empty now

    ## get old vlans and interfaces
    for i in "${oldvlans[@]}"
    do
        if [ "$line" = "switchport access vlan $i" ]; then
            ...
        fi
    done
    ### check for  "trunk allowed vlans" etc.
    regex="switchport trunk allowed vlan"
    if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]; then
        ...
    fi

    prev="${line}"
done < ...
```

(Or perhaps first check if the line matches `switchport access vlan` or `switchport trunk allowed vlan` and then decide what to do.)

Note that in regular expressions, `n*` means "zero or more letters `n`", *not* "a single `n` followed by anything", like it does in shell patterns. But in the `[[ str =~ regex ]]` test, the regex isn't anchored to the start/end of the string anyway (e.g. `[[ foobar =~ ob ]]` is true), so you don't need that trailing "match anything" anyway.

Some other programming languages might also provide better tools for string processing than the shells do.